# Why can't I completely remove myqsl from my CentOS 6 machine?

Tags: mysql, centos6, root

When I hit the command `yum remove mysql` I get the following error:

```
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror
Setting up Remove Process
No Match for argument: mysql
Error: File contains no section headers.
file: file:///etc/yum.repos.d/mysql-community-source.repo, line: 1
'mysql-connectors-community-source]\n'
```

I then proceed to `yum list installed | grep mysql` after wich I get:

```
mysql-community-common.x86_64
                     5.7.9-1.el6        @mysql57-community
mysql-community-libs.x86_64
                     5.7.9-1.el6        @mysql57-community
mysql-community-libs-compat.x86_64
                     5.7.9-1.el6        @mysql57-community
mysql57-community-release.noarch
                     el6-7              @/mysql57-community-release-el6-7.noarch
```

When I try to individually remove these with the command `yum remove mysql-community-common.x86_64`, I get:

[image]

**How do I get rid of this error?**

```
File contains no section headers.
file: file:///etc/yum.repos.d/mysql-community-source.repo, line: 1
'mysql-connectors-community-source]\n'
```

I even deleted the yum.repos for mysql but it didnt help, and because I didnt save it I had to recreate them from another virtual machine and copy pasted them....

**The hole point of this is so I can install a fresh installation of mysql but I cant because of the dependencies...**

**EDIT1**This is what I just tried and it failed as you can see:

```
[root@centos ~]# yum autoremove mysql
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror
No such command: autoremove. Please use /usr/bin/yum --help
[root@centos ~]# yum install autoremove
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror
Setting up Install Process
Error: File contains no section headers.
file: file:///etc/yum.repos.d/mysql-community-source.repo, line: 1
'mysql-connectors-community-source]\n'
[root@centos ~]#
```

Comment: what append why you try autoremove ?

Comment: I dont know what you mean by autoremove, but tell me what I should do?

Comment: `yum autoremove <package>` remove package and useless dependencies

Comment: @Froggiz check my EDIT1

Comment: If repo file is corrupt, this won't work. First correct it please.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, you don't need to delete a repo to uninstall the relevant pakages.

It's not working, because you have messed up your repo file for the relevant pakages and that's why `yum` can not work.

See the error log again, it clearly states, the file is faulty, it is missing the header section.

> Error: File contains no section headers. file:
>   file:///etc/yum.repos.d/mysql-community-source.repo, line: 1
>   'mysql-connectors-community-source]\n'

So you need to check the file `/etc/yum.repos.d/mysql-community-source.repo` and correct it.

I guess, while doing copy-pasting it didn't got pasted fully.

See below a repo file contents for MySQL 5.7 Community Server. Your file is missing the `[mysql57-community]` section I suppose.

```
[mysql57-community]
name=MySQL 5.7 Community Server
baseurl=http://repo.mysql.com/yum/mysql-5.7-community/el/6/$basearch/
enabled=1
gpgcheck=1
gpgkey=file:///etc/pki/rpm-gpg/RPM-GPG-KEY-mysql
```

Comment: My mistake, I didnt copy paste it right. Although autoremove didnt work (centos doesnt recognize and cant install the command), I had to manually remove each of those 3 components...